# Install RPM files in a HPC cluster (Centos 8) without root permission

Tags: rpm, hpc, centos8

How can I install some rpm files on a HPC cluster (Centos 8) while I do not have root permission.
I need to install it in my own directory and call it via my ./bashc_profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. For installing the RPM package you need root (or sudo) access. Full stop.

You can extract the content using rpmdev-extract and if it is some kind of script, you can put it somewhere.